# how to iterate dynamic response in angular 7 http get api call

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

i am getting dynamic response from angular7 http get method, the response is only one array of object and it will change every minute dynamically, i need to capture and iterate new and existing records of array object can any one guide me how to solve this

below added array object it will change every minute dynamically how can i iterate new and existing records

```
------------------------------------------------------------
[
    {
      "2018": {
        "score": "0.03726378083229065",
        "TxnNo": "2293760_1-2019r",
        "month_interest_std": "23.632556357702818",
        "m4_last_payment_amount": "1031.94",
        "firstInstalmentDate": "2/28/2018",
        "m6_balance": "15044.57",
        "m2_m1_balance": "0.06796083071380637",
        "period_max": "24.0",
        "paymentmethod_nan": "0"
      }
    }
  ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide some details on what you are wanting to do when iterating? If the keys of the objects in the array is what is changing, you can use `Object.keys(obj)` to get a list of the keys in the object which you can then loop over.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep both new and existing data from array, better you can store it somewhere in the local variable and iterate over it.

whenever new data comes push new data into existing array, like below -

```
fullData: Array<any> = [];

this.fullData.push({
      "2018": {
        "score": "0.03726378083229065",
        "TxnNo": "2293760_1-2019r",
        "month_interest_std": "23.632556357702818",
        "m4_last_payment_amount": "1031.94",
        "firstInstalmentDate": "2/28/2018",
        "m6_balance": "15044.57",
        "m2_m1_balance": "0.06796083071380637",
        "period_max": "24.0",
        "paymentmethod_nan": "0"
      })

<div *ngFor='let item of fullData'>{{item?.TxnNo}}</div>
```